# WooCommerce: Skip attribute in foreach if anotner attribute is part of the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, attributes

I show a list of attributes (colors) on my product page.

The list contains a lot of similar attributes like "blue", "light blue", "marine" and more.
To keep the list of attributes/colors short, I want to remove every version of blue if "blue" is part of the loop.

Here's the code of my loop:

```
<?php
global $product;
$pa_colors = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pa_colors', array( 'fields' =>  'all', 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ) );
if( $pa_colors ) :
?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $pa_colors as $pa_color ) : ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $pa_color->name; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I know, that I can check the loop if there is the color "blue" inside with something like this:

```
$color_blue = $product->get_attribute('pa_colors');

// Check if blue is in the attribute array:
if( strpos($color_blue, 'blue') !== false ) :

// Versions of blue to remove
$color_blue_versions = array('light blue', 'marine')
```

But how could I skip all the other versions of blue in `$color_blue_versions` from the foreach loop?

Comment: Why don't you output `blue` if `blue` exist? `if( strpos( $color_blue, 'blue' ) === false ): echo 'blue';` ?

Comment: because I would loose all the other attributes in the loop, like red or green. Sorry, just an example

Comment: Does blue, green, red always output first ? Do you have an example of the current outputs ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's always different. And you can think about features of a TV. If it features 4k output, I don't need the feature 1080p, which it also have for filtering but is not an highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `array_diff()`.

> Computes the difference of arrays.

- Source @ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

And here is a minimal example.

```
<?php
$colors = [ 'blue', 'light-blue', 'sea-blue', 'murmaid-blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red', ];
$exclude = [ 'light-blue', 'sea-blue', 'murmaid-blue', ];
$colors = array_diff( $colors, $exclude );
print_r( $colors ); ?>
```